# Wrong Limit in Mathematica 10.0.0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

```
Limit[(Log[(3+Sqrt[5])/2]/(2*Log[(1+Sqrt[5])/2]))^(-1-2*n), n -> Infinity]
```

Mathematica (wrong) output:

```
0
```

But this is correct:

```
FullSimplify[(Log[(3+Sqrt[5])/2]/(2*Log[(1+Sqrt[5])/2]))^(-1-2*n)]
1
```

And also this is correct:

```
Limit[(Log[4]/(2*Log[2]))^(-1-2*n), n -> Infinity]
1
```

Comment: Version 10.1 under Windows x64 gives `1` for the first input line.  This is probably a bug that has been corrected.

Comment: Thank you, I tested it under version 10.0.0.0

Comment: Gives 0 in version 9.0.1, and returns unevaluated in previous versions. Looks like the bug was introduced in version 9.

Comment: Version 10.0.2 also gives `1`.  Can anyone test 10.0.1?

Comment: 10.0.1 gives `1`.

Comment: @blochwave I'm removing the version tag because it is present at several versions (and we can't be sure in which ones)

Comment: @belisarius no you're right, sorry, not paying attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments, this bug has been fixed as of version 10.0.1.

```
Limit[(Log[(3+Sqrt[5])/2]/(2*Log[(1+Sqrt[5])/2]))^(-1-2*n), n -> Infinity]    

(* 1 *)
```